# Ruby on Rails - How to migrate code from float to decimal?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I've got a ruby on rails code which use float a lot (lots of "to_f"). It uses a database with some numbers also stored as "float" type.

I would like to migrate this code and the database to decimal only. Is it as simple as migrating the database columns to decimal (adding a decimal column, copying float column to decimal one, deleting float column, renaming decimal column to old float column name), and replacing "to_f" with "to_d" in the code? Or do I need to do more than that?

Thanks a lot everyone
Raphael

Answer (score 18):

You can easily use a migration to do this, and Rails will generate some of the code for you.

From your command prompt, create a new migration:

```
rails generate migration change_price_column_to_decimal
```

Rails will create the migration in the directory `db/migrate`. The filename will be a timestamp followed by `_change_price_column_to_decimal.rb`.

In the generated migration, you'll add `up` and `down` methods to convert the field:

```
class ChangePriceColumnToDecimal < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    change_column :products, :price, :decimal, :precision => 15, :scale => 2, null: false
  end

  def down
    # Either change the column back, or mark it as irreversible with:
    raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
  end
end
```

To perform the migration, run the appropriate rake task from your command prompt:

```
rake db:migrate
```

This will convert the database for you. Keep in mind that when converting from float to decimal you will lose some significant digits, depending on what you set `scale` to, though if you're dealing with prices of products, this probably isn't going to be much of an issue.

Comment: As a note here, `:decimal` is represented as a special fixed-precision type internally that avoids a lot of the issues involved with using actual floating point values. Some numbers simply cannot be represented as a float which leads to approximations and tiny but noticeable amounts of imprecision.

Comment: "when converting from float to decimal you may lose some precision".

Don't you mean the other way around?

Comment: @Dennis Well, no. If you convert from decimal to float, you gain precision, but lose accuracy. If something costs $1.99, then storing 1.99 is accurate; but 1.98999999999999999375851 may be more precise, but it's certainly less accurate, and will cause a variety of strange errors. It could also be that I've misused the word "precise".

Comment: If anyone is wondering why a single `change` method isn't used instead of the `up` and `down` methods, it's because [the `change` method doesn't support the `change_column` migration definition](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#using-the-change-method).