# rails float different than database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, optimization

I can't understand why my float value in my model is less precise than the one in database.

We have this table:

```
  create_table "materials", force: :cascade do |t|
    # ...
    t.float "tiling_rotation"
  end
```

When I try to save a float with 16 decimals, this happens:

```rb
m = Material.create!(tiling_rotation: 1.5707963267948966)
p m.tiling_rotation # 1.5707963267948966
m.reload
p m.tiling_rotation # 1.5707963267949
p m.id # 1234
```

At this point, I figured that my database would trunk the value, but when I check, I get this:

```sql
select tiling_rotation from materials where id = 1234
-- 1.5707963267948966
```

MY database column has the type `double precision`

How is this possible? How can I set the float precision of **ruby** to the same than my database?

Comment: I don’t know what’s causing the floating point precision loss, but it looks like you’re storing 90 degrees as radians. Maybe you can avoid the issue by storing "tiling rotation" in degrees?

Comment: Hi, sure we could. But it doesn’t solve lost of precision.

Comment: That depends on the values you are storing, e.g. `90` can easily be stored _exactly_, even as a float. It’s much harder to store ½.

Comment: sure. we use degrees now. But now I have another attribute, called `foo` and guess what? Same problem.

Comment: My point is: floats are approximations, you use them if precision isn't that important. The difference between both numbers in your example is less than 0.0000000000002°. If that isn't enough and you want more precision, or maybe an _exact_ value, then floats might not be the right data type to begin with. And using an irrational representation doesn't make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

From a little bit of reading on ActiveRecord, this may be down to precision issues on the mapping between database decimals and float in Ruby.

Try changing your database schema so that "tiling_rotation" is a decimal with precision 16.  Reference : [Ruby on Rails - How to migrate code from float to decimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13255987/ruby-on-rails-how-to-migrate-code-from-float-to-decimal)